# Fading image in and then out again

Tags: love2d

So I'm attempting to create a splash screen that fades in the image `splash1.png` and then after a couple of seconds fades it out again. So what I've done is make the screen start out completely black, then change the alpha of the color to 1, and next its supposed to fade back to black. But currently it seems to be getting hung up on the `fadein` stage and not moving beyond that. If anyone has any fixes or alternatives to what I'm doing it would be much appreciated.

```
function love.load()
    timer = 0
    alpha = 0
    fadein  = 300
    display = 500
    fadeout = 900
    splashScreen = love.graphics.newImage("images/Splash1.png")
end

function love.update(dt)
    timer=timer+dt
    if timer<fadein then alpha=timer/fadein  print("fadein")
    elseif timer<display then alpha=1  print("display")
    elseif timer<fadeout then alpha=1-((timer-display)/(fadeout-display))print("fadeout")

    else alpha=1 end

end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255, alpha*255)
    local sx = love.graphics.getWidth() / splashScreen:getWidth()
    local sy = love.graphics.getHeight() / splashScreen:getHeight()
    love.graphics.draw(splashScreen, 0, 0, 0, sx, sy) -- x: 0, y: 0, rot: 0, scale x and scale y
end
```

Comment: Have you figured this out since posting? If not, I'll try and figure it out and get back to you after work.

Comment: I've sort of just given up on it for now. If you have any idea, that would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this took me so long to answer. The following code should achieve what you're looking for:

```
function love.load()
    timer = 0
    alpha = 0
    fadein  = 3
    display = 6
    fadeout = 9
    splashScreen = love.graphics.newImage("image.png")
end

function love.update(dt)
    timer = timer + dt
    if 0 < timer and timer < fadein then 
        alpha = timer / fadein  
    end
    if fadein < timer and timer < display then 
        alpha = 1  
    end
    if display < timer and timer < fadeout then 
        alpha = 1 - ((timer - display) / (fadeout - display))
    end
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1, alpha)
    local sx = love.graphics.getWidth() / splashScreen:getWidth()
    local sy = love.graphics.getHeight() / splashScreen:getHeight()
    love.graphics.draw(splashScreen, 0, 0, 0, sx, sy)
end
```

The main differences from your code are:

- I switched the `elseif` statements to `if` statements and gave upper and lower bound for the `timer` checking. The issue with your version is that first `if` statement would be true every time, so the program wouldn't even look at the others;
- I changed the values for `fadein`, `display`, and `fadeout`. If you're using `dt` as your counter for animations be aware that it counts quite slowly, for a standard monitor the example values I put should give you a good starting point:
- I changed your `setColor` values to scale from `[0, 1]`. I'm pretty sure the 255 scale works, but  I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked perfectly. And thank you for giving detailed explanations for your solution.

Comment: Glad it helped!